# Laravel Job - No handler registered for command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to get a simple job running exactly like the example in the Laravel Documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes -  but I get this error: "No handler registered for command [App\Jobs\SendReminderEmail]".

I followed the instructions to make the jobs table and even the failed_jobs table and have the exact example code.

I assured that the handle() function is there so I don't know what else can be missing.

Regards.

**Update with code**:

First I used the class in the Laravel example but then I simplified it to this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SyncFromJson extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct()
 {
     //
 }

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    //
    $var = "fooooo";
    \Log::info("job is running!!!", $var);
}
}
```

To call the job I created a simple method in a controller that dispatches the job:

```
$job = (new SyncFromJson())->delay(3);
$this->dispatch($job);
```

Also tried this:
`$this->dispatch(new SyncFromJson());`

Comment: We need code and more context...

Comment: Just updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, I was having a similar problem and implementing 'SelfHandling' seems to have fixed the issue.

Try changing this:

```
class SyncFromJson extends Job implements ShouldQueue
```

To this:

```
class SyncFromJson extends Job implements ShouldQueue, SelfHandling
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why we have to add this interface even though it is marked as deprecated in Laravelu 5.2? Without it, I get the above-mentioned mistake :(

Comment: You saved me, I was implementing Illuminate Queues in our custom app and couldn't figure that part out for several hours. Just adding that fixed it and called the internal job handler. THANK YOU A LOT!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. In my case it turned out it was the incorrect provider in app config that was the problem. I used a previous project as a framework for my new project and inherited the Laravel collective bus package (That was not required.) The moment I removed the collective bus package ( laravelcollective/bus ) , ran composer update and replaced

Collective\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,

with

Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,

everything worked fine. This may be a similar issue?