# Laravel Job SelfHandling not working

Tags: laravel, command, handler, jobs

I've been trying to use self handling jobs in my laravel project, but I got the error:

> No handler registered for command

Here is my Job code:

```
class JobTest extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;


    public function __construct($data)
    {}

    public function handle()
    {}
}
```

I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Job - No handler registered for command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312042/laravel-job-no-handler-registered-for-command)